# Bash TAB autocomplete, locale and accented files

Tags: macos, bash, autocomplete, locale, filenames

On OSX, my current locale is set to English UTF-8, but it doesn't seem be act consistently. When I create two files, one with a regular `a` and another one with an accented `á`, autocomplete stops working correctly. Here's what I'm seeing:

```
/tmp/locale $ locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

/tmp $ mkdir locale && cd locale
/tmp/locale $ touch foobar
/tmp/locale $ touch foobár

# when I type "foo" and hit TAB, bash will autocomplete with "ba"
# if I keep pressing TAB, both files will be displayed:
/tmp/locale $ ls foo<TAB>
/tmp/locale $ ls fooba<TAB>
foobar  foobár

# however, at this point, I can only finish writing "foobar"
# no combination of characters will allow me to autocomplete "foobár"
# if I type "foobá" and hit TAB, no files are displayed:
/tmp/locale $ ls foobá<TAB>
/tmp/locale $ ls foobár<TAB>
# <no files displayed for either>

# Using wildcard won't work either:
/tmp/locale $ ls foobá*
ls: cannot access foobá*: No such file or directory

# but this works correctly (wtf?):
/tmp/locale $ ls foobár
foobár
```

On a Linux box, none of this happens and things work just as anyone would expect. What gives?